# How to debug remote typescript vitest unit test with nvim-dap?

Tags: typescript, configuration, remote-debugging, vite, neovim

My vite typescript unit test is served by a remote server on the `remoteserver` domain name using the following command:
`node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0 ./node_modules/vitest/vitest.mjs run --threads false src/backend/api.spec.ts`

When I attach nvim-dap with the config below, it fails with this message:

> Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?).

My nvim-dap configuration:

```lua
            dap.adapters = {
                node2 = {
                    type = 'executable',
                    command = 'node',
                    args = {
                        '/var/git/github.com/microsoft/vscode-node-debug2/out/src/nodeDebug.js'
                    }
                }
            }
```

```lua
            dap.configurations.typescript =
                {
                    {
                        type = "node2",
                        address = "remoteserver",
                        port = 9229,
                        request = "attach",
                        sourceMaps = true
                    }
                }
```

**Update:** Interestingly, vscode can stop at the debugger, although it ignores the source map, which is set to true (generated).